# MongoDB Error - Can't get Player Data

Tags: mongodb, bukkit

I'm working on a Framework for a Minecraft Server and I'm running into a constant error while retrieving player data from a MongoDB database. I have both a proxy plugin and a spigot plugin that the framework is shaded into.

For the proxy plugin, I can get and store the player data in my `PlayerCache` (A map that assigns UUIDs to `PlayerData` objects), but however, for the spigot plugin, I cannot. It returns a null pointer, saying that the data is not found in the cache, even though I am sure I called the `cacheData` method.

I believe what is going on is that I'm not allowing enough time for the database to get the information and cache it.

Spigot code:

```
@EventHandler
public void onLogin(PlayerLoginEvent event)
{
    PlayerCache.getInstance().cachePlayer(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
}

@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event)
{
    event.setJoinMessage(null);
    event.getPlayer().setDisplayName(PlayerCache.getInstance().getCachedRank(
            event.getPlayer().getUniqueId()
    ).getColor() + event.getPlayer().getName()); //Throws a null pointer.

}
```

`PlayerCache`:

```
public void cachePlayer(UUID uuid)
{
    PlayerData PD = PlayerManager.getInstance().getPlayerData(uuid);
    this.cache.put(uuid, PD);
}

public PlayerRank getCachedRank(UUID uuid)
{
   return this.cache.get(uuid).getRank();
}
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Could you add the exception stack trace? (Just for debugging purposes)

Comment: What just comes to my mind is the following: Have you made sure that you're initializing `this.cache` in the `PlayerCache` constructor? This is a mistake I often make which leads to a `NullPointerException` as put and get methods can't be executed on null.